# What's the HTML code to limit the access to my web-page?

Tags: html, authorization

I have a question about HTML. I know that there is this mechanism that wouldn't allow users to get a direct access to a web-page unless they enter a password and a name. What's the HTML code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a manual section in PHP describing how to output HTTP headers that force an HTTP Auth. You can't do it with HTML alone.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Personally I'd prefer the `.htaccess` method, but in the end, both do the same thing.

---

PS: Getting pretty cold 'round here.

Answer (score 6):

HTML is used to format information and present it, not do logical operations like authentication. For this you need to configure server settings (google .htaccess permission) or use a scripting language like PHP etc.

Comment: ps - still quite nice here, though the changing leaves are quite pretty

Comment: Hello, Devin, thank you for your answer, but I definitely remember once I bumped into an HTML code that was doing that. I remember I even used it, but too bad I lost it later.

Comment: @brilliant: No, you didn't, because HTML can't do that. You must have run into something else and thought it was HTML.

Comment: Oh , really? Okay,than I must have had a wrong recollection. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, you would have to do your work server-side for authentication. I saw that you mentioned that you "bumped into an HTML code" that was doing password "stuff."  Are you sure you weren't referring to the [HTML Password Field Form](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms06.htm)?  This is a field to hide a password that is being typed.  However, as Devin said, this is only for presentation.  The real work has to be done elsewhere.

Comment: Hello, Jason, I think it was a piece PHP code that I took for HTML as at that time new nothing about PHP and figured it was all HTML. 

Thanks for your link though, it's quite interesting.